# Are specific questions on linux-based certification material appropriate here?

Tags: discussion

I'm studying for the LPIC-1 exam and would like to ask specific questions regarding some course material that doesn't make sense.  Is it appropriate to ask those questions here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the course material is about Linux, and if you're not violating any copyright or confidentiality agreement you've signed, sure.

Comment: Absolutely.  Just to be clear, this wouldn't be "homework" questions or any sort of braindump stuff.  I'd just like a place to ask linux-based questions if the author doesn't describe concepts in a way that makes sense to me.  Thanks.